# Regex to match a list of field:values

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am writing a program (for python homework assignment) that searches a database based on a query

the queries are formatted like this (arbitrary field names)
Field:Value
And they are separated by commas for multiple

EG

Name:George Bush, Address:  1234, b-street, Email: email@email.com

I need to extract the field and value

I've been messing around with different regular expressions but I'm a pleb

Right now my 'best' regex is this: ([\w@ -]+): *([\w@ -]+)

but this doesn't capture values with commas in it correctly and could miss arbitrary characters

### Here are more examples of my desired behavior

Query: "Name: George Bush"

Match: 'name', 'George Bush'

---

Query: "Address:1234, street street"

Match: 'Address', '1234, street street'

---

Query: "Name: George Bush, Address:1234, street street, f13ldna-me:---"

Match1: 'name', 'George Bush'

Match2: 'Address', '1234, street street'

Match3: 'f13ldna-me' , '---'

Comment: How do you decide that you have a new identifier?  For instance, in the case of `"Name: George Bush, Address: xxx"` is it that there are characters preceding the `:` ?

Comment: I think that the intended behavior is that the presence of the comma character lets you know that another identifier character is coming. I don't think they realized that some fields (eg address) contain commas


I decided to just go against the assignment description and just use a designated separator character ';'

Comment: @JeremiahGelb Can you update the question with the example data and the expected matches when adding that delimiter?

Comment: I got it to work with the delimiter. I'm not going to update the question with the delimiter. Your answer works great without the delimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the matches from your example data,  you might use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching not a whitespace char or a `:` to match the field as in the example data is does not contain a whitespace.

For the value part you could also use a negated character class matching not a `:` followed by matching either a comma and 0+ whitespace chars or assert the end of the string.

```
([^\s:]+):\s*([^:]+)(?:,\s*|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BUm58e/1)